# Why does phpmyadmin take so long for an alter table statement

Tags: php, google-maps-markers

It's been an hour and I have a table with 4 million rows. I forgot to add a column; thus, I wrote an alter table statement to add the column.

```
ALTER TABLE gblah
ADD zipcode varchar(5)
```

I am not sure why this takes forever.

Comment: There are 4 million rows.  It needs to add that field for each and every row.

Comment: Funny how this is phpmyadmin's fault.

Comment: Another reason to privatize the postal system!

Answer (score 1):

Any alter statement in MySQL will take time proportional to the number of rows in the table. Any time you modify a table it needs to add that column to each record, so it must touch each record. This is not a function of PHPMyAdmin. Also, any time you add a column you should do it with the application offline, if there's any lock contention that will hold up the alter statement.

Although, 4M isn't that many rows, with contention, and depending on your structure and database engine, it may take a while (I think MyISAM alters take longer than innodb because MyISAM requires whole table locks and handles concurrency less well).

Comment: So times of 1-2 hours are normal then?

Comment: Normal all depends on the speed of your machine, the complexity of your schema, any database load in addition to the alter statement, what database engine you use... There are a few factors.

It's not atypical for a large alter to take hours. In the case of a table with BILLIONS of records, typically they'll start a database server separate from the production system with a recent data dump, add the column, then replay transactions between the dump and the time it finished.

Answer (score 1):

If you watch the MySQL processes through phpMyAdmin, you'll see the entire table is copied, changed, and then copied back. A big table will take a while. Additionally, if you don't have the hard drive space to make the copy, the ALTER query will fail. I learned that the hard way trying to alter a 2GB table on a small server.